# Launch a batch file, wait until it closes and do something in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I'm working on an application in C# Winforms but I want it to launch a batch file from a specified directory, wait until it closes and do something when closed, like opening another form.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\directory\batchfile.bat").WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Batch File execution finished.");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how do I tell it to do something like show a message box? Do I put the code in the next line?

Comment: MessageBox.Show("message goes here.");

Comment: yes, put it on the next line. It will show the message once the batch file is complete.

Comment: Tysm for the solution! That was a nice memory refresher.